# Using if then else in HTTP request in JMeter

Tags: automation, jmeter

I have a test suite of simple API calls, one request requires that the response of the previous request contains a string in the response.

Is it possible to do the following?

Step 1. I have an API GET HTTP request that which returns say a value in the response:

```
"value":"test"
```

Step 2. I need to check if the response contains the string stated above so it can then do another HTTP request; if not, then ignore the request and proceed with the rest of the tests in the suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate your test plan as follows:

- Thread Group

  - First Request (which returns `"value":"test"`)

    - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
  - [If Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)

    - Second Request

Configuration for Regular Expression Extractor:

- Reference name: `value` (or any other variable name)
- Regular Expression: `"value":"(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Configuration of If Controller

Put `"${value}"=="test"` in the Condition field.